# what does result_type() mean of a Class using boost

Tags: boost

I started going through boost library recently and
came across a sample code which is as follows

```
Class A : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
typename A::result_type();
```

I couldn't understand what `result_type()` will do here.

Answer (score 0):

It result type is a nested typedef indicating the return type of the visitor.

This is so `boost::apply_visitor` knows what return to expect (even if the various overloads of `operator()` return possibly different types).